# nodejs stream no output

Tags: node.js, stream

I am new to nodejs stream. I try to connect the child process stream with the parent's, but it doesn't work. Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code? here is my code.

```
var child = require('child_process');
var ps = child.spawn('wc', '-l');

ps.stdout.pipe(process.stdout, {end: false});
process.stdin.pipe(ps.stdin, {end:false});

ps.stdin.on('end', function(){
    process.stdout.write('ps stream ended');
});

ps.on('exit', function(code){
    process.exit(code);
});
```

Comment: have you tried the third argument of `.spawn` where you define which streams will be shared like this `spawn('wc', ['-l'], { stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', process.stderr] });`

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things with this code.
First, the second argument of `.spawn` should be an array.
Second, you basically need to pass a filename to wc to get any output.

So for example if you do something like

`var ps = child.spawn('wc', ['-l', 'package.json']);`

or

`var ps = child.spawn('ls', ['-a']);`

It works just fine.